# Recursively Merge And Sort A List

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a recursive merge and sort function and I've spent a few hours on it but I just get frazzled. I've looked at several resources, and I have the answers, but I'm trying to understand, not just copy paste. Also this is homework and it seems like that would be cheating.

I was hoping that someone could try and give me a little direction on where to go next. I've coded a function that recursively breaks the list into individual parts. The merging and sorting is really throwing me off though.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class TheEngine {

    private static List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            test.add(rand.nextInt(100));
        }
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(test.size());
        splitter(test);
    }


    public static List<Integer> splitter(List<Integer> list){



        int mid = list.size() / 2;

        if(list.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        else if(list.size() % 2 == 0) {
            //TODO: EVEN
            splitter(list.subList(0, mid));
            splitter(list.subList(mid, list.size()));
        }
        else if(list.size() % 2 == 1) {
            //TODO: ODD
            splitter(list.subList(0, mid));
            splitter(list.subList(mid, list.size()));
        }

        return list;
    }


}
```

Comment: You're running exactly the same code no matter if the length is even or odd. You can just turn that into a single else block.

Comment: You're also discarding the return values of the recursive calls, which are what you're meant to be merging.

Comment: What's the difference between the body of `else if(list.size() % 2 == 0)` and else `if(list.size() % 2 == 1)`?

Comment: This is going to sound weird, but if I change it to just "splitter(list.subList(0, mid));
   splitter(list.subList(mid, list.size()));" I get an error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.subList(Unknown Source))